# Adding Strings and ssize_t?

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I have a question on adding strings and data types. What does it mean to use them in such arithmetic? Does `body + size` mean that it is creating a new block of memory that includes both of them?

The following is just an excerpt of the code:

```
char* body;
ssize_t size = load();
char buffer[512];

    body = realloc(body, size + octets);
        if (body == NULL)
        {
        return -1;
        }
        memcpy(body + size, buffer, octets);
        size += octets;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *body;
```

`body` is not a string, it's a pointer. If it's initialized appropriately, it might *point* to a string, but it's not a string itself.

```
ssize_t size;
```

`size` is an integer.

```
body + size
```

This is *pointer arithmetic*.  It doesn't allocate any memory; it merely takes a pointer value and an integer, and yields a new pointer value.  If `body` points to an element of an array, then `body + size` points to an element `size` positions later in the same array. (If `body` doesn't point to an array element, or if `body + size` is outside the bounds of the array, then the behavior is undefined.)

```
memcpy(body + size, buffer, octets);
```

For example, suppose `body` points to the initial (0th) element of an array of 100 `char` elements, and suppose `size == 30`.  Then `body + size` is a `char*` value pointing element 30 of the same array.

Look up "pointer arithmetic" in any decent C textbook or tutorial.